# Encerramento de menu lê o target como undefined

Tags: javascript, funções, eventos

Estou montando um menu simples que se encerra ao clicar no "document", porém, aparece que a propriedade target não pode ser lida para undefined

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"


//Vars
var userMenu = document.querySelector(".menu-holder");
var navButton = document.querySelector("#menu-nav-button");
var doc = document.documentElement;
//Functions
function toggleMenu(event){

    if(navButton.classList.contains("active")){
        navButton.classList.remove("active");
        userMenu.classList.remove("active");
        doc.classList.remove("active");
    }else{
        navButton.classList.add("active");
        userMenu.classList.add("active");
        doc.classList.add("active");
    }
}
function closeMenu(event){
    if(event.target == document.documentElement){
        navButton.classList.remove("active");
        userMenu.classList.remove("active");
        doc.classList.remove("active");
        console.log("oloco")
    }else{
        console.log("deu ruim")
    }
}closeMenu();
```

Como posso corrigir o erro, e por que ele acontece ?

Comment: Colega, voce não está passando nenhum parâmetro para a função "closeMenu" e ela está esperando algum. :
 function closeMenu(event) ...
closeMenu(semEventoDefinido);

Comment: como assim ? não entendi muito bem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifiquei o Script acima, o mesmo se resolveu apenas removendo a declaração `CloseMenu()` ao fim da criação da função

Answer (score 0):

A sua função chamada `closeMenu`era para receber algum parametro : `function closeMenu(event){`. Esse (event) é o parametro.

E você chama a função sem passar valor algum para ela : `}closeMenu();`

Tente passar algum valor para esta função.

Comment: passei o valor event mesmo mas não rodou